# openpyxl chart and table design

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm new to Python
I'm trying to figure out how to keep non alterate an Excel sheet that contains tables formatted and design syle graphs. I have made modifications with the help of Openpyxl to the source of graphs and after save, when opens the chart is loosing all special style design (i used to be black font, after save and opening chart is on a white font with minimal design style).
Also only parts of a table border disappears.
Any idea what to import ?
Thanks

Comment: This is very vague. You should include some of the code your using and more specific examples of what styles are not being preserved.

Comment: Code is made to move data between 3 excels, not relevant to my problem

Comment: For example, in excel 2010 my particular graph had been styled using preset under the TAB "design" - style 5 (black background and glow to the lines) after saving the file in Py those styles are lost and all I got is a minimal display of this graph.